# Google Chrome both does and doesn't correctly handle EXIF images

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, exif

An application I'm developing has the requirement to correctly handle EXIF images in Google Chrome. Here's an example image:

[image: Example]

[View on Github](https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples/blob/master/Portrait_6.jpg) | [View in browser](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples/master/Portrait_6.jpg)

If you click the "view in browser link" above and you are in google chrome, the image will be correctly rotated; "top" in the image will be at the top instead of at the left.

If you open developer tools when viewing the image on Chrome directly, you see a source like:

```
<body style="margin: 0px; background: #0e0e0e;">
    <img
        style="-webkit-user-select: none;background-position: 0px 0px, 10px 10px;background-size: 20px 20px;background-color: white;background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%),linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%);"
        src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples/master/Portrait_6.jpg">
</body>
```

If you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3o8Lbrzu/) from that source, the image is rotated!

How is Chrome handling EXIF when an image is opened directly? Is it possible to do this on my own site?

Comment: https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=crbug.com/498233 also https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=f:ImageDocument+shouldRespect

Comment: Yeah, `image-orientation` seems like exactly what I need, but it doesn't work in chrome.